# CSS position fixed and absolute not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, css-position

Hello this is really weird unless I'm missing something. On my website I have a static header bar which is set to position fixed everywhere works perfectly except on 1 page and I cant figure out why. Also this happens in chrome only. The div with class "top-bar is positioned : fixed"

```
<header>
    <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="top-wrapper">
            <a href="/" style="display:block !important;"><div class="logo"></div></a>
            <a href="/add-event" style="display:block !important;"><div class="add-event button"></div></a>
            <a href="/events" style="display:block !important;"><div class="all-events button"></div></a>
            <div class="search-wrapper">
                <form class="searchform" action="" method="post" onsubmit="window.location.href = '/search/'+$('.searchfield').val()+'/1';return false;">
                    <input class="searchfield" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search...">
                    <input class="searchbutton" type="submit" name="search-submit" value="Go">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

and here is the css:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0) !important;
background: url(../gfx/field_bg.png) repeat-x left top;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute !important;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
z-index: 998;
```

Comment: What tag(s) does this CSS associate with? This is useless otherwise.

Comment: top-bar class sry Forgot to mention it clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In inspector, toggling off `-webkit-transform: translate(0) !important` on `<header>` solved the issue for me.